# Express route for single element

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express 4.9.0.
I have the following code in my user.js file inside route folder.

```
/* Get User by id. */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log('find user ' + req.params.id);
  User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(user);
    }
    return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Later, in app.js:

```
app.use('/users', users);
```

However, when i navigate to `http://localhost:3000/users?id=546e5640f5fea84a345abe2c` the route is never hit. Calls to other routes work fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the route you currently have, you'd need to make your request url this: `/users/546e5640f5fea84a345abe2c`.

If you want your route to match the request url you're currently trying (`/users?id=546e5640f5fea84a345abe2c`), then you would instead do:

```
/* Get User by id. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('find user ' + req.query.id);
  User.findById(req.query.id, function (err, user) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(user);
    }
    return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm beginning with rest and still have to get used!